# AccessControlException in YARN mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

Recently we have upgraded to CDH 5.1.3 & YARN, we are getting following errors in mapreduce job

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)                             [1829/1922]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.callGetBlockLocations(DFSClient.java:1140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getLocatedBlocks(DFSClient.java:1118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchLocatedBlocksAndGetLastBlockLength(DFSInputStream.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.openInfo(DFSInputStream.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.<init>(DFSInputStream.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.open(DFSClient.java:1291)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$3.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryParser.<init>(JobHistoryParser.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.CompletedJob.loadFullHistoryData(CompletedJob.java:335)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=mapred, ac
cess=READ, inode="/user/history/done_intermediate/abc/job_1412716537481_0426-1412782860181-abc-PigLatin%3ACategory+li
ft+for+pixels%3A9259-1412782882528-1-1-SUCCEEDED-root.abc-1412782867082.jhist":abc:supergroup:-rwxrwx---
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1717)         [1804/1922]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1621)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServe
rSideTranslatorPB.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenod
eProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformatio
```

any workaround this problem

What permissions we should have on /user/* & /user/history/*

Answer (score 0):

Got resolved after deleting /user/history/done_intermediate/*